# Plotting Positional Data to show smoothness

Tags: networking, graph, smoothing, evaluate

I have written a networked game (basically a prototype) which implements different smoothing algorithms such as interpolation and extrapolations etc, I have positional data which can be printed out from the console and copy and pasted into a text file.

I want to know how i can get this into a chart using a program such as Excel, or if there are any other evaluation techniques you could recommend. The purpose is to easily compare the positional data with other data.

In my mind it would have a top down view, looking sort of like a track of where the object has been, i have the coordinates, just not sure how to draw the graph quickly and easily using a tool such as Excel!

Thanks very much!

oh here is an example of the data as it might help

```
,15.751465,33.538113 
,18.151794,25.811478 
,19.495346,21.973022 
,22.628979,14.682346 
,24.365070,11.008181 
,28.246189,4.080928 
,30.273335,0.735968 
,34.930840,-5.853795 
,37.285229,-8.955721 
,42.614258,-15.034148 
,45.294456,-17.888378 
,51.419174,-23.527817 
,54.313343,-26.019697 
,60.745731,-30.817125 
,63.899082,-33.008480 
,70.894211,-37.166611 
,74.556221,-39.166740 
,81.631203,-42.427887 
,85.215569,-43.934799 
,92.895576,-46.541466 
,96.762917,-47.703796 
,104.548660,-49.463692 
,108.342720,-50.187851 
,116.485268,-51.145309 
,120.289818,-51.464588 
,129.282242,-51.511787 
,132.348267,-51.445812 
,140.325546,-50.714527 
,145.365982,-50.025780 
,152.171997,-48.671867 
,156.216812,-47.713547
```

If need be I can reformat the data, atm I was using the comas as delimiters in excel. The data is basically x/z axis coordinates so basically over a 2D plain. I'm really desperate for some help, so thanks!

Edit: that data was meant to come out in columns, 2 across and multiple rows down!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try a scatter plot interactively online here http://www.shodor.org/interactivate/activities/ScatterPlot/

generating it in excel or such may vary depending on tool or version

[edit] it seems doesn't support copy and paste (at least at my browser) so you have to enter data manually (without the former comma) and you have to choose the "scatter" plot type. at least you can get an idea of how it looks like and see if it fits with your needs

Comment: Hey thanks, this is a really good and useful site, got such a fast answer. For people that read this in the future, if you have a massive list of data like i do, save it in a test file, and import it into excel. You can can then use the SCATTER plot as the guy above said, no other graphing mode is really suitable.. Using import saves you from writing out tons and tons of data.